# water effect in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, quartz-graphics

I'd like to have a water effect on a background layer in my app. The effect doesn't need to react to touch or anything - it just needs to wave an image a little bit.

CCWaves3D seem ok, but leave have nasty black artifacts around the edges when I run it. Similarly CCShaky3D. CCLiquid brings my app down from 20fps to 5fps..

Is there any other effect I might want to try out? Or perhaps I'm using the current effects in a wrong way?

```
id shaky = [CCShaky3D actionWithRange:4 shakeZ:NO grid:ccg(15,10) duration:4];
id liquid = [CCLiquid actionWithSize:ccg(15,10) duration:1];
id wave = [CCWaves3D actionWithWaves:18 amplitude:80 grid:ccg(15,10) duration:10];
```

Bonus question - where can I find any good documentation for cocos2d effects? I found default cocos2d docs utterly useless & wasted a couple of hours trying to google before asking this question :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed performance issues when building/running in debug mode.  Have you tried to build/run in release mode?  Also, are you experiencing this on the device and not just on the simulator?

Unfortunately, I have not found alternate documentation specifically for cocos2d effects.  Here are a few links to posts and sites I have gathered for many different resources including tutorials, tools for making tile map games, using zwoptex for making sprite sheets, using vertex helper for making a verticies plist file for box2d/chipmunk collision detection instead of just rectangles, and sites for images & sounds:

[Cocos2d Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293457/cocos2d-resources/4061868#4061868)

[Need 2D iPhone graphics designed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104124/need-2d-iphone-graphics-designed/4111974#4111974)

http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/knowledge-base/tutorial-professional-cocos2d-xcode-project-template/

I have found Ray's Tutorials especially helpful along with viewing the test applications included with cocos2d.

Happy coding!

Comment: Performance issues during debugging - why didn't I think of that, thanks (seriously - I only tested in debug mode).
Also thanks for link - they will be very helpful once I get to work on my next cocos2d app.

Comment: Your welcome - glad it helped!  I know it drove me crazy for over a day until I figured out that the debug mode was the culprit.